# Publish to IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, publish

I need to publish a solution in visual studio 2015 with 3 projects, 1 client web, 2 server side api and WS. Is it possible to publish the complete solution in IIS? If I could not publish like this, what would it be like?
Thank you!

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Deberias preguntar aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a package by right-clicking on The Solution and hit Publish choose with publish profile you want and the your package should be created Then use msdeploy.exe to deploy your website

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:<verbName>
             -source:<provider>[=<pathToProviderObject>
                      [,<providerSetting>=<providerSettingValue>]]
             [-dest:<provider>[=<pathToProviderObject>
                      [,<providerSetting>=<providerSettingValue>]]
             ]
             [-<MSDeployOperationSetting> ...]
```

Msdeploy Documentation [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569106%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)